# Botframework Emulator not listening localhost

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

BotFramework Emulator 4.14.1

Mac 13.4.1

Running my bot app locally, message endpoint is http://localhost:8000/messages and put that to emulator configuration.
Have a pair of valid app id and app password used in both emulator configuration, and my bot SDK.
No ngrok running.
The emulator console says

```
[15:35:52]Connecting to bot on http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages
[15:35:52]Emulator listening on http://[::]:61206
[15:35:52]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots)
```

My message endpoint running on localhost 8000 **is able to** receive activities from the emulator.

However, I cannot send activity to the emulator from my app using SDK. Error log says

```
msrest.exceptions.ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=61206):
Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/conversations/ee48c330-1471-11ee-9c52-8fb0458b1baa%7Cdebug/activities/ee54d120-1471-11ee-9277-8191548fd1ef 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffb391b7c0>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Looks like no one is listening on localhost:61206. Looks like the emulator is listening on `http://[::]:61206` but not `localhost:61206`.

Could someone give me some hints on why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix. And no, I didn't change my messaging endpoint to port 61206, that's not supposed to change. Real problem is that emulator is listening on IPv6 while the sdk is sending requests to IPv4 address. So I have to use ngrok (v2, not v3) to work together with the emulator, and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework Emulator not being able to connect to the bot running locally.

> The error shows that the emulator is listening on http://[::]:61206, but the application is trying to send activities to `http://localhost:61206`, which results in a connection error.

- Modify the endpoint configuration in your bot application to listen on `http://localhost:61206` instead of `http://localhost:8000/messages`.

[image]

Check the bot app is running and actively listening on `http://localhost:61206.`

Restart both the bot app and the BotFramework.

Verify that the [firewall or any security software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-policy-configure-bot-protection?pivots=portal) on your machine is not blocking the connection to localhost on port 61206.

Verify any application or service is already using the port 61206.

Ensure that there are no conflicting network configurations or proxies that might interfere with the connection.

[image]

If you have any custom networking settings, such as modifying your hosts file, revert them to the default configuration.
By following these steps, you should be able to establish a connection between your bot application and the BotFramework Emulator running locally.

References taken from [GitHub - botframework-sdk.](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk) and [blog-bot Framework- Emulator.](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2019/04/your-first-web-app-bot-using-the-local-bot-framework-emulator/)

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).